# How to fix "Both <script> and <iframe> used" suggestion for google adwords code

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads-api

Currently i'm using Google conversion code and Google analytic code for my site but i checked through Google Tag Assistant then its show suggestion for Google Conversion code while Google analytic code is changed into "Working" state.

my site url [https://shopbansri.com](https://shopbansri.com/shop/)

[image]

Comment: I've visited the site with the google tag assist and I'm not seeing the adwords conversion tracking. What are the steps to recreate?

Comment: Please now check site again. https://shopbansri.com/shop

Comment: Did you find out about this? I see the same in my page, and clicking 'more info' takes you to a screen with explanations for other errors

Answer (score 3):

To solve your problem add

```
google_conversion_format = 3;
```

aferter those rows

```
var google_conversion_id = 973934432;
var google_custom_params = window.google_tag_params;
var google_remarketing_only = true;
```

Comment: it seems strange... in the source code of your website it work fine